# set.seed publishing model in R

Tags: r, data-science

Do you include set.seed() as part of the final model when you are ready to distribute/expose your model to the real word? Do you only use set.seed() for validation during training and validation?

Once you decide on your method, parameters, etc., do you run the model without setting the seed and that is the model you launch? Or do you pick the seed that performed the best during validation?

Thanks!

Comment: The main purpose of `set.seed()` is reproducibility; that is, to ensure others get the same results where random number generation is involved.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt different seeds give that variant results unless you have parameters that involve random sampling of features or observations. Still i believe you answered your own question. To reproduce the Exact result you would need to include the seed value as well with your final model. It is not of really great significance however, so you dont need to really worry about it too much.